# Date picker for command line

Tags: node.js, datepicker, command-line-interface, vorpal.js

How are datepickers handled in a CLI environment? Is the most common route to just treat it as a text input with custom validation? Are there custom "controls" that keep formatting and only allow you to edit the digits (think `__/__/__`). Would an interactive calendar (possibly rendered using [cli-tables](https://github.com/Automattic/cli-table) and `arrow keys`/`enter`) be possible/better?

#### Extra Details

I'm developing a command line app using Node.js and the [Vorpal](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) and I would like some sort of datepicker interface.

Other libraries like [Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js) provide easy-to-use picklists, checkboxes, and input validation. They act just as they would within a GUI.

The app in question is essentially a task manager app, allowing you to edit tasks to say when you started and stopped. So the dates that are required would refer to ranges (start -> stop) and all relatively recent.

Comment: Are you looking for an input that interprets dates? Or could you give a basic idea of how this might look?

Comment: I can understand your confusion, I will update the question to better address the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a datepicker (GUI) in a CLI app before, but it's totally possible to make it with Vorpal and create a Vorpal extension for it, [using these commands](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/api-%7C-vorpal.ui#uiredrawtext-text).

I've successfully done this type of thing once, in building [`less` for Vorpal](https://github.com/vorpaljs/vorpal-less), which does screen redraws based on arrow key movements, etc, which would be a similar endeavor. You can check out the source [here](https://github.com/vorpaljs/vorpal-less/blob/master/src/less.js) for how I do it.

But that's a bit of work.

The other idea (and maybe this can tie into the above) is to simply make a smart-validating date input.

There's a ton of Javascript date libraries [like this one](http://sugarjs.com/dates) that can parse human date strings and standardize them. So you would just do a normal `Inquirer` input, and add some validation to it.

---

Does that help?

Comment: That does help. I know I can make a date picker using various methods (specifically the Vorpal API), but wasn't sure if it was something done before. Since I can't find ANYTHING online about datepickers in the terminal I wasn't sure if there was some UX factor I wasn't considering.

Comment: I think complex CLI environments are just starting to mature. JS is one of the most accessible language and one couldn't do these things before `blessed` and `vorpal`, so that's the only explanation for it not existing, I believe. Building CLIs has been hard. And yeah, I've looked at a lot of resources on CLIs, and haven't seen anything like that.

Comment: That's honestly why I started this project, ease of entry. It only takes an hour to two to add rich CLI support to a library when you use something like `vorpal` or `blessed`. I will be sure to let you know how a custom date/date range picker goes, probably best as an extension to `inquirer.js`.

Comment: Totally! Okay great, I agree.